# Opu.Ua.Client - C# - OPC UA - How can a client recover a session (permanent/durable) with subscription(s)?

Tags: c#, session, opc-ua, recover

I'm new to OPC UA. 
I've installed a Server OPC for sumulation (Integration Objects\OPC UA Server Simulator). 
I'm using c# with Opc Foundation std library.
I've successfully implemented the client following https://stackoverflow.com/a/59179379/4745606 
So, I have implemented subscription with
`subscription.FastDataChangeCallback = OnDataChange;` 
Everything works.. 
But when I kill the client I see that on the server the session remain and also the subscriprion remain (for more time than the session). 
When I restart the client a new session is created with a new subsciption.. 
So, how can I recover the previous session? 
I unsucessefully tried Session.Recreate() but a session is required as a parameter and documentation is not so good.
All the messages missed while the client was offline, will be recovered in that way?
Or I have to set durable/persistent session/subscription somewhere?